# Does java have a Frequency table?

Tags: java, object

Does Java have a built in Frequency Table? I remember using one in one of my classes and I know Python has one, but I do not remember if I built one on my own or if Java has one for use.

Comment: What kind of frequency table? `collections.Counter`?

Comment: Not built-in, but several libraries have them, e.g. [Guava's `Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

Comment: You can easily implement one with `Map`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume by "frequency table" you mean a map of value-to-count.
The answer is **no**.

It's not much of a stretch to create a well-behaved one though:

```
Map<T, Integer> freq = new HashMap<T, Integer> () {
    @Override
    public Integer get(Object key) {
        return containsKey(key) ? super.get(key) : 0;
    }
}
```

Then when using you don't have to clutter your code with null checks when getting a frequency:

```
freq.get(value);  // returns zero for not found
```

Or when incrementing:

```
freq.put(value, freq.get(value) + 1); // always works, won't throw NPE etc
```

Comment: +1 For delegation and providing a reasonable solution to getting a key that doesn't exist in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Not built-in but you can check [Apache Commons Statistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//userguide/stat.html). It has an easy Frequency table builder that allows to find frequency, cumulative frequency, counts, etc.

Comment: How would I implement this?

Comment: The link given has examples. Basically create a new Frequency object. and use addValue(). When finished call toString and you have a table.