# How to display quantity of each item entered in ArrayList String?

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of `String` where user enters number of items and when they enter the keyword `stop`, code displays the number of items entered and then the how many items are on their `list`. for example, if i entered apple, apple, Apple, banana, stop, total number of items is 4 and apple x2 Apple x1 banana x1. 
i'm having trouble with the last part, which is displaying the quantity of whatever is entered. this is what I have so far
EDIT: I don't know/haven't used HashMap, I know only up to using ArrayList

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Enter the what you wish to purchase:");
    Scanner read= new Scanner(System.in);
    String item  = read.nextLine();

    while(!item.equals("stop")) {
        list.add(item);
        item = read.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Total items: " +list.size());
}
}
```

Comment: Use a HashMap<String,Integer> instead of an ArrayList. The string key is the name of the item e.g. Apple, Banana and the Integer value is the quantity bought

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word frequency count Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122394/word-frequency-count-java-8)

Comment: Is there a way to do it *without* using HashMap? It's something I haven't learned yet, though it may be easier to use in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Java's `HashMap` object.  Each key is guaranteed to be unique so if the key already exists you can increment by one, or create a new key.  For example:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

while(!item.equals("stop")) 
{
     if (map.containsKey(item))
     {
         // increment the value by one probably not the most effficent way
         Integer count = map.get(item) + 1;
         map.put(item, count);
     }
     else
     {
         map.put(item, new Integer(1));
     }

     item = read.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to keep track of them items as well as the count of each item, you might want to use a HashMap instead.

```
Map<String, Integer> items = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

if (items.contains(item)) {
  items.put(item, items.get(item) + 1);
} else {
  items.put(item, 1);
}

// print all items
for (String s : items.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(s);
}

// print quantity of each item
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : items) {
  System.out.println("Item " + entry.key() + " was entered " + entry.value() + " times!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. My solution is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261944/1166537

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> table = new HashMap<String, Integer> () {

            @Override
            public Integer get(Object key) {
                return containsKey(key) ? super.get(key) : 0;
            }
        };

        System.out.println("Enter the what you wish to purchase:");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String item = read.nextLine();
        int itemCount = 0;

        while (!item.equals("stop")) {
            itemCount++;
            table.put(item, table.get(item)+1);
            item = read.nextLine();
        }

        for(String key : table.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(key +" -> "+ table.get(key));
        }
        System.out.println("Total items: " + itemCount);


    }
```